# Facebook Audience Network - (#606) Application is rejected

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I am implementing Facebook Ads in my app.
I included the SDK via Gradle and

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.17.0'
```

I then do

```
final InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(ctx, channel);

interstitial.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onError(Ad arg0, AdError arg1) {
        Log.e("Ads Facebook Error",arg1.getErrorMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad arg0) {
    }
});

interstitial.loadAd();
```

Manifest has :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

As a result, I don't get any ads and the listener returns in onError with the message

```
Ads Facebook Error: Channel : 186801684845556_309815189210871 / Error : (#606) Application is rejected
```

Why is the application rejected now when it worked until recently? Do I have to setup something else with Facebook? Can't remember I had to do that last time.

Comment: i this your InterstitialAd id is not still live that's why the error is come. just check app id is live or not in your facebook developer audiance network.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there was something wrong in the backend, I just forgot this question, it's long solved for us :) If you want you can put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i this your Interstitial Ad id is not still live that's why the error is come. just check app id is live or not in your facebook developer audience network

You just wait for the your app purchase id for live.